# What is the use of @connect decorator in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning React and following a few tutorials, I came across this code:

```
import React                  from 'react';
import TodosView              from 'components/TodosView';
import TodosForm              from 'components/TodosForm';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as TodoActions       from 'actions/TodoActions';
import { connect }            from 'react-redux';

@connect(state => ({ todos: state.todos }))

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { todos, dispatch } = this.props;

    return (
      <div id="todo-list">
        <TodosView todos={todos} 
          {...bindActionCreators(TodoActions, dispatch)} />

        <TodosForm
          {...bindActionCreators(TodoActions, dispatch)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is a todo application and this is the main page, it loads 2 more small `components`. I understood almost everything but I couldn't get few things:

- What does `connect` do? I know you have to pass 4 params(I couldn't exactly get what are those 4 variables though).
- How is the implementation of `@connect` decorator, how the code will look like after transpiling?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Redux and react-redux documentations are pretty complete on this subject. On what `connect` does for you : http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html, on `connect`'s API and what are the four arguments: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: Well, I got to know about the 4 arguments from the same link, but I couldn't understand it properly from there, that's why I asked a question here :) :)

Comment: Ok i'll post a quick answer, but i doubt i can do any better than the documentation! :)

Comment: I would add that the official documentation never uses decorators anywhere because it is an unstable feature and may change later. Don’t use it unless you’re OK with it breaking someday.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Redux keeps your application's state in a single object called the store. `connect` allows you to connect your React components to your store's state, that is to pass down to them your store's state as `props`.

Without the decorator syntax, your component's export would look like

```
export default connect(state => ({todos: state.todos}))(Home);
```

What it does is that it takes your component (here `Home`) and returns a new component that is properly connected to your store.

Connected here means : you receive the store's state as `props`, and when this state is updated, this new connected component receives the new props. Connected also mean that you have access to the store's `dispatch` function, which allows you to mutate the store's state.

The four arguments are :

- **mapStateToProps** you probably don't want to inject all your store's state in all your connected components. This function allows you to define which state slices you're interested in, or to pass as `props` new data derived from the store's state. You could do something like `state => ({todosCount: state.todos.length})` and the `Home` component would receive the `todosCount` prop
- **mapDispatchToProps** does the same thing for the dispatch function. You could do something like `dispatch => ({markTodoAsCompleted: todoId => dispatch(markTodoAsCompleted(todoId))})`
- **mergeProps** allows you to define a custom function to merge the props your component receives, the ones coming from `mapStateToProps` and the ones coming from `mapDispatchToProps`
- **options** well, some options…

Comment: @BharatSoni the decorator syntax is explained : it rewrites your class declaration as `connect(connectOptions)(MyComponent)`, that is all. `connect` returns a function that takes a component as a param and returns a new component. For the rest, it's not a copy-paste, but anyway, sorry if it doesn't help you more than the docs, i did my best :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this brilliant explanation about the React with Redux, this is the best explanation so far.