# redux-thunk dispatch does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a problem with thunk and async dispatching. So here is my code:

```
function fetchProvider() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    graphqlService(fetchProviderQuery)
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_PROVIDER,
          data: result.data.data.CurrentProvider,
        });
      });
  };
}

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProvider();
  }

  render() {
    const { provider } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>id: {provider.id}</li>
          <li>name: {provider.name}</li>
          <li>description: {provider.description}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  provider: state.provider,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchProvider: () => dispatch(fetchProvider()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

I don't know why but dispatch inside fetchProvider action creator does not work. graphqlService works well and in moment of dispatching FETCH_PROVIDER action data passed to dispatch is correct but then something goes wrong and reducers doesn't called with this action. What possibly could cause this problem?

Comment: Did you decorate your `Dashboard` using the `@connect` decorator? Ifaik you need it, to be able to call the dispatch function. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553814/what-is-the-use-of-connect-decorator-in-react-redux

Comment: @TomDoodler, yes. It's the last line in the code above.

Comment: Is `state.provider` null or undefined before the `FETCH_PROVIDER` action fires?

Comment: @MinusFour iit's initial state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. It was caused by incorrect initialization of react-router-redux middleware. I passed middleware constructor to applyMiddleware instead of constructed middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Your `thunk` has to return also the promise, or it won't work as expected.
Just modify slightly your `fetchProvider` function

```
function fetchProvider() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return graphqlService(fetchProviderQuery)
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_PROVIDER,
          data: result.data.data.CurrentProvider,
        });
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work as well. But actually it hasn't to return anything.

Comment: Yeah apologies. I assume that `redux-thunk` is correctly initialised?

Comment: Here is initialization:

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, routerMiddleware)
);

Comment: I also tried to change order of middleware but it also didn't help.

Comment: Everything looks fine.. that's really strange. If you inspect `dispatch` right before calling it, can you actually see that it is a function? Is it defined?